# What is a general expression for a symmetric $N$-mode beam splitter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, unitarity

**BACKGROUND**

A symmetric beam splitter can be represented as
\begin{equation}
\hat{B}^{(2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
and according to [Zukowski *et al.*](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.55.2564), the three-mode equivalent is
\begin{equation}
\hat{B}^{(3)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & \alpha_3 & \alpha_3^2 \\
  1 & \alpha_3^2 & \alpha_3^4
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_3 = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$.

**QUESTION**

I would like to generalize the above to a symmetric $N$-mode beam splitter. I understand that there has to be a unitarity requirement. Based on the two-mode and three-mode examples, I also notice that there is some kind of pattern whereby the matrix elements might be powers of $\alpha_N = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{N}}$. However, I'm not really sure how to assemble them into a matrix. I'm looking for something that would look like this:
\begin{equation}
\hat{B}^{(N)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & ⋯ & 1\\
  1 & \alpha_N^? & \alpha_N^? & ⋯ & \alpha_N^? \\
  ⋮ & ⋮ & ⋮ & ⋱ & ⋮ \\
  1 & \alpha_N^? & \alpha_N^? & ⋯ & \alpha_N^?
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Comment: It is really just the Discrete Fourier Transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the matrix you want is just the Fourier matrix.  Thus, if $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/N}$ so that $\alpha^N=1$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&1&1&\ldots&1\\
1&\alpha&\alpha^2&\ldots &\alpha^{N-1}\\
1&\alpha^2&\alpha^4&\ldots&\alpha^{2(N-1)}\\
\vdots&\vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\
1&\alpha^{N-1}&\alpha^{2(N-1)}&\ldots&\alpha^{(N-1)(N-1)}
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}

BTW this matrix has a number of "nice" properties.  See for instance:

> Mehta, M. L. (1987). Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the finite Fourier transform. Journal of Mathematical Physics, 28(4), 781-785.

Comment: It's worth remarking that for systems with dimension $d=2^k$ you can also use a Hadamard matrix to only have real entries.

Comment: @fulis ... to model what?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch to model a symmetric d-mode lossless beam splitter (obviously with a $1/\sqrt{d}$ factor in front). See this for example https://doi.org/10.1364/OPTICA.388912 and https://doi.org/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.010320

Comment: @fulis Hm, this is puzzling. How can both be correct? How do those beamsplitters differ?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch even for a 2-mode BS the transformation matrix is not uniquely determined because the phases are not measurable, [see this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746572/the-action-of-5050-quantum-beam-splitter). To go between different the 4-mode descriptions you need 2-mode mixing operations in addition to phase shifts, but that isn't too surprising if you consider that any N-mode path unitary can be decomposed into 2-mode unitaries, for example with the [Clements decomposition](https://doi.org/10.1364/OPTICA.3.001460).

Comment: Such a unitary is fully determined by the single-photon input/output relations, so a balanced beam splitter is just any way to map the different inputs to equal superpositions over the output modes. That doesn't require any photon self interference, so you're free to set the internal phases in the decomposition to whatever you want.

Comment: @fulis I don’t quite understand your argument.  Of course the internal phases are important.  The number of beamsplitters grows like $\frac12 n(n-1)$ but the number of parameters grows like $n^2$ so you will eventually necessarily have internal phases, unlike the $2\times 2$ case where all phases  can be placed at the front or at the back.  How could the internal phase *not* be important?